# XAML code window is zoomed in (fonts and icons) but no other windows are in Visual Studio 2021

Tags: visual-studio, zooming

Basically, everything is fine and normal EXCEPT for my XAML code files which are zoomed in to ridiculous proportion. Not just the font, but the menus in that widget as well:

[image]

If you look to the tabs and text surrounding the window, you can see how comically large the XAML window is. When I open another XAML file, it was undocked so it goes off the screen and I can't even see the controls on the other side (it doesn't show on my second monitor; it just gets cut off).

This is not a font problem, it's a zoom problem of some kind but I haven't been able to find any kind of zoom control that works (there are several keyboard shortcuts listed in other questions, but none of them do anything).

Any other file type displays normally (C# code etc).

Comment: Did you check `Options / XAML Designer`, to see if everything is fine there? Does Ctrl+Wheel do something?

Comment: CTRL-Scroll increases and decreases the font size, but it does it for ALL windows. When I make the XAML sensibly sized, the rest of my code looks like ants. Additionally the menu size is still overlarge meaning the problem is still there.There are no setting in options/XAML Designer that seem to have an effect.

Comment: So are you saying that if you go to `Options / Fonts and Colors / XAML Designer`, the font size is ok, like 12/13? (I guess it's ok, because when I increase the font size, the upper dropdowns remain small) If you close VS and create a new project, the issue remains?

Comment: Yes. 11/10 on font. It's fine on a new project. It's also fine if I pop-out the XAML to its own window (though it isn't for my other file in the same project which is already popped out and also weirdly sized.

Comment: Alright, so now you know it's something project specific. Can you try renaming the `.vs` hidden folder and/or any `.suo` files in the solution's main folder? You can probably just delete them, but in case you want to exactly find out what caused this, you can try removing/restoring one by one.

Comment: Note, I remote to this computer from a laptop and a desktop system and something about that process seems to be relevant. It seems to have stopped somehow. Still no idea why.

Comment: I just encountered this today. Did you ever find any kind of explanation or a definitive resolution?